# Checksums on TCP

Tags: tcp, network-programming, checksum, crc

Is TCP not responsible for making sure that a stream is sent intact over the wire by doing whatever may become necessary as losses etc. occur during a transfer?

Does it not do a proper job of it?

Why do higher application-layer protocols and their applications still perform checksums?

Comment: @cnicutar the one that is biting me very hard at this very moment is fetch (wget-like tool) on FreeBSD downloading a 60 MB file over a mobile internet connection.

Comment: Call me uninformed, but I'm not aware of any application-layer protocols that perform checksums. Can you mention, specifically, the application-layer protocols you are thinking of?

Comment: @Robᵩ You are right. My formulation was perhaps not really clear. Checksums are performed by applications that use protocols like http, ftp to download large files or by package managers of operating systems. So it happens around and not as an integral part of such protocols. Although I am not sure if we can say that safely when we consider bittorrent and similar peer-to-peer data transfer protocols as well; that unsureness led to my ambiguous formulation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While TCP does contain its own checksum, it is only a 16-bit checksum and it is certainly possible for a multi-bit transmission error to slip by the TCP checksum mechanism. This is quite rare, but it is still possible and I have in fact seen it happen (once or twice in a couple of decades).

A robust protocol will want to use a higher-level hash function to assure integrity of transmitted data. Having said that, not many applications that transmit a small amount of data go to this trouble. Bulk transfer applications (such as a package manager or auto-update mechanism) will usually use a cryptographic hash function to increase the assurance of data integrity.

Comment: Keeps happening to me at this very moment :) I am about to give up and wait until afternoon for my primary internet connection to come back to life before going on.

Comment: If you are repeatedly getting the same problem, then it's unlikely to be a TCP transmission error. Those kind of multi-bit transmission errors aren't repeatable.

Comment: `fetch` on `FreeBSD` (albeit in VirtualBox) is not of the same opinion (and in my case also hope). Maybe it is because I am not knowledgeable enough to 'operate' `fetch` properly and it does restart downloads on checksum errors.

Answer (score 1):

TCP ensures that TCP packets are delivered reliably, using checksums to trap errors introduced during transmission, and retransmitting lost or damaged packets as required. When a packet is transmitted it is retained in a retransmission queue until the peer host acknowledges receipt; if no acknowledgement is received within a certain timeout period then the packet is retransmitted. But the host won't keep retransmitting a packet forever - if a packet repeatedly fails then TCP eventually gives up and closes the connection.

Higher-level protocols assume that TCP works reliably (a fair assumption) and use their own checksums or whatever to check that the higher-level data stream arrived safely. I've written lots of buggy sockets applications that screwed up their own higher-level buffers and mangled the application data stream!

In any production-grade TCP/IP stack with a robust application I think you can be confident that the problem is that your connection is dropping out. Or you might have a buggy application, but I doubt that your fetch/wget is buggy.