# Does HTTP use a checksum? Why/why not?

Tags: http, tcp, checksum

As I understand, TCP has a [relatively reliable checksum mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494416/checksums-on-tcp), but there is a very small yet present chance of it returning a false positive.

Does HTTP use an application level checksum (perhaps a hash)? If not, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup (: the specs for HTTP/1.1 ([RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)) allow the use of a `Content-MD5` header. Take a look at its [section 14.15](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.15).

Copy-pasted:

> The Content-MD5 entity-header field, as defined in [RFC 1864](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1864) [[23](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#ref-23)], is
> an MD5 digest of the entity-body for the purpose of providing an
> end-to-end message integrity check (MIC) of the entity-body.

Comment: That's just for the payload (and also, deprecated).